# Pandasを用いてデータクリーニングがうまく行きません。

Tags: python, python3, pandas

csvを読み込んだあとにpandasを用いて、指定カラム内のカンマ(,)を削除したいのですがうまく行きません。
以下のコードを実行しました。

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('csv/gaku-mg1712Ver2.csv', encoding='shift_jis')
df["国内総生産"] = df["国内総生産"].str.replace(",","")
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('csv/gaku-mg1712Ver2.csv', encoding='shift_jis')
df["国内総生産"] = pd.to_numeric(df["国内総生産"]) #数値変換
```

前者はエラーが出ませんでしたが、データをエディタで確認すると変わりないようでした。
後者は下のエラーが出ました。

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "120,801.2 "
ValueError: Unable to parse string "120,801.2 " at position 0
```

imgはcsvのデータフレームです

[image: これがcsvのデータフレームです]

Answer (score 1):

そもそもなのですが、読込時に`thousands=','`を指定して桁区切り記号を取り除けばよいかと思います。

```
import pandas as pd
url ='http://www.esri.cao.go.jp/jp/sna/data/data_list/sokuhou/files/2017/qe173_2/__icsFiles/afieldfile/2017/12/07/gaku-mk1732.csv'
df = pd.read_csv( url, encoding='shift_jis', skiprows=7,header=None, thousands=',')
print(df)
```